# Drag and drop file upload (knockout + webapi + asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I am looking for Drag And Drop File Upload component, using Knockout + .NET WebApi technologies.

I have found File Api project, it doesn't support old browsers, but I can live with it. The code is here: https://github.com/khayrov/khayrov.github.com/tree/master/jsfiddle/knockout-fileapi.

It creates custom Knockout Bindings, some code parts:

HTML:

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" data-bind="file: imageFile, fileObjectURL: imageObjectURL, fileBinaryData: imageBinary"/>
```

Knockout JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.file = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).change(function() {
            var file = this.files[0];
            if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                valueAccessor()(file);
            }
        });
    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var file = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var bindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        if (bindings.fileObjectURL && ko.isObservable(bindings.fileObjectURL)) {
            var oldUrl = bindings.fileObjectURL();
            if (oldUrl) {
                windowURL.revokeObjectURL(oldUrl);
            }
            bindings.fileObjectURL(file && windowURL.createObjectURL(file));
        }

        if (bindings.fileBinaryData && ko.isObservable(bindings.fileBinaryData)) {
            if (!file) {
                bindings.fileBinaryData(null);
            } else {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    bindings.fileBinaryData(e.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfourtunately I do not understand if I can reuse this code and integrated it within some Drag And Drop File upload component?

Is there any existing DnD file upload component that can be used with knockout + webapi?

Comment: Although I am using knockout in the project, I don't use a custom binding for it, but the library http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ has proved to work well for me.

Answer (score 0):

See this http://jsfiddle.net/3LT9d/

```
function noopHandler(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

ko.bindingHandlers.dropUpload = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        element.addEventListener('dragenter', noopHandler, false);
        element.addEventListener('dragover', noopHandler, false);

        element.addEventListener('drop', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            var value = valueAccessor();
            for (var i = 0; i < evt.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
                value.push(evt.dataTransfer.files[i]);
            }
        }, false);
    }
};
```

How it works:

1. The dropUpload custom binding populates an observable array with the dragged files
2. To upload the files, the new API FormData is used since backward compatibility seems to be not an issue. FormData is easier to work with.
3. Follow this article to find out how to allow your webapi to accept FormData
   http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

Comment: Hmm.. it better to name the custom binding as dropFiles